# How to remove my account from app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am fairly new to app scripts and coding in general.

I have created a code using app script on google sheets. Some of the code sends emails to other users that would be submitting a form.

I was wondering how I would go about removing my account from the file or script ( not sure of the exact terminology ) and it run/link to another user's account.

Answer (score 0):

First some concepts

Google Apps Script has  "owner" and "editor" (sometimes also called collaborator), "active user" and "effective user".

The owner is the user who created the container or the stand alone script.

The active user is the one that is running the script. The effective user will be the same than the active user when the script is ran from the script editor, from drawing having assigned a script or by a simple trigger (onOpen, onEdit, onSelectionChange) but might be different when the script is called by an installable trigger or by the client-side API (`google.script.run`)

If you don't want to be the container/script owner anymore, you have to transfer the ownership to an editor or to a company by moving the file to a Shared Drive.

If an editor makes a copy of the container/script, your account will not be "linked" to the copy.

When a user try to run a script from the script editor, if the script uses methods that require authorization to run they will be required to authorize the script before it is being executed using their credentials.